# Ler arquivo CSV utilizando como delimititador o caractere "?"

Tags: python, pycharm

Quando faço um download de um arquivo CSV no Windows (PyCharm) da escola, funciona, mas quando faço o mesmo download no MacOS em casa (PyCharm), sai com caracteres abaixo:

```
Manege;Parc;Type;Design;Statut;Ouvert;Vitesse ( mph ) Air;Talpon
Park;Acier;Volant;En op�ration;2002;46,6 Boomerang; Family Theme
Park;Acier;Assis;En op�ration;1993;47 Cobra;Paultons
Park;Acier;Assis;En op�ration;2006;31,1 Colossus;Thorpe
Park;Acier;Assis;En op�ration;2002;45
```

Como corrigir este problema?

Comment: Tene colocar esta linha no inicio do seu código `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Embora tenha o `?` no texto, o delimitador não parece ser ele e sim o `;`

Comment: A codificação do arquivo não é a que o PyCharm está tentando abrir.
Aparentemente o PyCharm pensa que UTF8 mas eu chutaria que ISO-8859-1(latin1) já que funciona normalmente no Windows.